# Image classification issue in adjacent images

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, classification

I classified large number of images captured by the same sensor so images look to be similar in spectral response.

However, the result I get is different for the same class in two neighboring images (see the images).

[classification result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovLme.png)

I don't know if this is the problem of classifier or pixel values.
I checked pixel values which look consistent and the classifier is well tested but still the problem in there. Any idea where the problem might be?

Thank you

Comment: Well, as you said, the problem can only be in the classifier or the data. Perhaps your classifier is not as well tested as you thought, but without any other information it's not possible to give any helpful response. Maybe if you explain how you trained your classifier, it might be that someone can spot some flaw in your methodology.

Comment: Hi Roger, I used RF classifier which can be found here https://code.google.com/p/randomforest-matlab/ The author said that it has been well-tested but still I have the same problem when I run it on tile-based images.